# Symfony2 - Doctrine ArrayCollection methods coming back as undefined

Tags: symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

This is odd.  I have an entity that can contain an ArrayCollection of other, related entities.  When I make a couple of helper methods to allow me to add/retrieve the value of a singular entity, I get a Symfony2 exception telling me the method is not defined.  I'm including the namespace, so I'm at a loss as to what the problem is.  Code (names changed slightly due to a NDA) below:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// ...

public function setThing($thing)
{
    $this->things->add($thing);
}

public function getThing()
{
    return $this->things->current();
}
```

What's really strange is that it's throwing the exception at `current()` but not `add()`:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Thing::current() in /home/kevin/www/project/vendor/acme/my-bundle/Acme/MyBundle/Entity/MyEntity.php line 106

Judging by the error, it looks like it's not treating `things` as an ArrayCollection.  Is there any way to force `things` to be an ArrayCollection?  I already have the following:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection things
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Thing", mappedBy="other")
 */
private $things;
```

But I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Do you have a method `add` in your `Thing` class?

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the object before the call to `getThing()`?

Comment: No.  Again, it looks like it's 'forgetting' that `things` is supposed to be a collection at that point.

Comment: @cheesemacfly, I have no idea how to do that in this instance.  The entity is being used to populate a form view, so the call is buried beneath a few layers of Symfony2 form generation stuff.

Comment: If you put the `var_dump()` it's gonna appear on top of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd.  I was able to work around it by checking its underlying type:

```
public function getThing()
{
    if (get_type($this->things) === 'ArrayCollection') {
        return $this->things->current();
    } else {
        return $this->things;
    }
}
```

The form now appears, correctly, with no exceptions.

Maybe it lazy-assigns an ArrayCollection if there's more than one related entity, and leaves it as just the related entity if there's only one? :shrug:

Comment: @I3I0 is correct may just be missing parentheses after ArrayCollection; like so: $this->things = new ArrayCollection();

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize ArrayCollection in your entity constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->things = new ArrayCollection;
}
```

otherwise you got `null` instead `ArrayCollection` for new entities

Comment: I did that in an answer than another person has since deleted.  The problem remained even after doing that.